# Swift Function Bug

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I'm trying to use a Function from a ObjC Framework.

```
fileServer.listShares({(_ shares: [SMBShare], _ error: Error?) -> Void in
if error != nil {
    print("Unable to list the shares: \(error)")
}
else {
    for share: SMBShare in shares {
        print("Got share: \(share.name)")
    }
}
})
```

And it gives me this Error: `Cannot convert value of type '([SMBShare], Error?) -> Void' to expected argument type '(([SMBShare]?, Error?) -> Void)?'`

Any Ideas?

> Xcode suggests to put `Insert ' as! ([SMBShare]?, Error?) -> Void'` in the end, but this would mess up the Function.

Comment: `listShares` expects a closure whose parameters are of types `[SMBShare]?` and `Error?`; your closure has parameters of types `[SMBShare]` and `Error?`. Make `shares` optional and you should have a valid call. (Note that of course, you'll need to unwrap `shares` in order to use them.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs because expected types are `[SMBShare]?` and `Error?`.
I advice you to simply change the types as following:

```
fileServer.listShares({(_ shares: [SMBShare]?, _ error: Error?) -> Void in
    if error != nil {
        print("Unable to list the shares: \(error)")
    }
    else {
        for share: SMBShare in shares {
            print("Got share: \(share.name)")
        }
    }
})
```